# How to determine if a column is boolean from cursor object?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I've result of a select query in a cursor object. I've some Boolean columns in the table. The value for Boolean type in SQLite is 0 or 1 depending on if they are false or true respectively. There are columns of int type too which can have value as 0 or 1 or other integer value. I want to return the value of a column from the cursor as,

```
if column is of boolean type
   return true if value = 1
   return false if value = 0
else 
   return the same value
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: so you want that if integer column has value 1 true is returned? im little confused.

Comment: @sajmon_d Only for boolean column I want the result as true or false not for int

Comment: @Cthulhu cursor.getType will never returns boolean. Even for type boolean it gives integer :(

Comment: @Jai SQLite doesn't have a boolean data-type. You could try somehow determining the **size** of the field.

Comment: Figuring out whether a 0 is meant to be false or a zero is generically impossible, it's semantics.  You could make a boolean[] array that does it for you though, after putting in the values by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to determine if a column is boolean from cursor object?

So at first, `SQLite` does **not have booleans type** only integer, string, float, blob. So my suggestion is simply test value for int column and based on result perform appropriate action.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, whereArgs);
int value = 0;
String[] intColumnNames = {columns};
int index = 0;
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   while (index < intColumnNames.length) {
      do {
         value = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(intColumnNames[index]));
         switch (value) {
            case 0:
               // do some action
            break;
            case 1:
               // do some action
            break;
            default:
               // do some action for other cases
            break;
         }
      } while(c.moveToNext());
      index++;
   }
}
```

Comment: what if the other columns have some 0/1 values?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I also thought for the same solution. But there are cases in which the column type is int and they have values 0 or 1

Comment: so you think you have more int columns? and you want to test all columns, ok?

Answer (score 0):

As I have not faced similar problem before So I cannot post a gurranteed answer. but your question seems really interesting and after searching a bit I think one solution might be an option..

at first step before reading data determing the datatype of the column. For this the following links may be helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298521/931982

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106349/931982

Then if you find that the column type is boolean then follow any of the solution provided by other two member.

N.B. it is not a confirmed answer, just posted my thinking. I would have commented this but it is too large to write in comment :(

Answer (score 0):

While its true that SQLite doesn't have a BOOLEAN storage type, there's nothing to stop you defining a column with BOOLEAN as a data type.  It will be stored as NUMERIC.  Your application can use PRAGMA table_info( to get the data type and only do your true/false check if it is BOOLEAN.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
int columnNumber = 11;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   if( cursor.getInt(columnNumber) > 0){
//true
}

}
```

As there is no Boolean Data type in sqlite to use boolean you need to have data type `INTEGER`
`SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).`
[More Details](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: this will fail for other column type which are of type integer

Comment: @Jai read my edited answer if you dont know in&out of system dont down vote